# How to add a header in Iron's AfterMiddleware?

Tags: rust, iron

I want to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` for every response my app will make.

According to [the docs](http://ironframework.io/doc/iron/middleware/trait.AfterMiddleware.html), `AfterMiddleware` is exactly for this

> In the common case, a complete response is generated by the Chain's Handler and AfterMiddleware simply do post-processing of that Response, such as **adding headers** or logging.

So I tried to use this like:

```
struct CorsMiddleware;

impl AfterMiddleware for CorsMiddleware {
    fn after(&self, req: &mut Request, res: Response) -> IronResult<Response> {
        res.headers.set(hyper::header::AccessControlAllowOrigin::Any);
        Ok(res)
    }
}
```

But I get the error `cannot borrow immutable field "res.headers" as mutable`. I'm not sure if this caused by immutable `Response` variable type, but as this is the trait function signature, I can't change it. So, how am I supposed to mutate something immutable? It would be weird to copy the whole response just to add one header, if that's even possible.

Comment: Also it would be awesome if the guy who clicked downvote will explain what exactly I did wrong when created this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest solution

> use `mut` variable

```
struct CorsMiddleware;

impl AfterMiddleware for CorsMiddleware {
    fn after(&self, req: &mut Request, mut res: Response) -> IronResult<Response> {
        res.headers.set(hyper::header::AccessControlAllowOrigin::Any);
        Ok(res)
    }
}
```

In Rust when you are the owner of data you can do anything with them, so this should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Actually it was exactly what I wanted to do, but for unknown reason I did `res: &mut Response` instead, and this, obviously, is illegal. My understanding of Rust syntax is a big mess for now because I tried to read too much info in a short time period.

Comment: The left hand side of an argument in a function declaration is a pattern, so just like `let mut res = …` would work to make a mutable binding, `mut res` works to make a mutable binding.

Comment: Instead of use Hyper dependecie, you can do it like that:
 
`use iron::headers::{ AccessControlAllowOrigin }; `          `res.headers.set(AccessControlAllowOrigin::Any); `